# How to ban a specific oracle user from accessing to specific listener?

Tags: oracle

I have two listeners L1 AND L2, L1 is listening on port 1521 while L2 is listening on port 1522.The oracle instance will register the database to L1 and L2 after startup.
Let say I have two users, U1 and U2.i would like to bind the L1 to U1, L2 to U2.Both U1 and U2 do not allow to connect the listener which is not the same as the listener they bind to, how can I make such configuration in oracle?

Comment: What problem are you actually trying to solve? I suspect you're barking up the wrong tree, and there's a better way of doing what you require.

Comment: The listener does not perform any authentication, only handshaking

Comment: I agree with @Phil - what problem are you trying to solve? What's to be gained?  That's like trying to block a telephone call from Fred if the call is routed through one switchboard, but accept if routed through another.  In fact, why do you even have two listeners?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution:

1. Create a new service on the instance

   `exec DBMS_SERVICE.CREATE_SERVICE('S1','s1.orcl.com');`

   `exec DBMS_SERVICE.CREATE_SERVICE('S2','s2.orcl.com');`
2. Start created services

   `exec DBMS_SERVICE.START_SERVICE('S1');`

   `exec DBMS_SERVICE.START_SERVICE('S2');`
3. Use netmgr tool to add created services on each listener

   - on listener1 select "Database Service" from drop down menu
   - click on "Add Database"
   - Fill "Global Database Name" with "s1.orcl.com'
   - Fill "SID" with original instance sid.
   - Same with listener2 but with "Global Database Name" with "s2.orcl.com'
   - Save network configuration
4. Restart both listeners

   `$lsnrctl stop listener1`

   `$lsnrctl stop listener2`

   `$lsnrctl start listener1`

   `$lsnrctl start listener2`
5. On client side edit the `tnsnames.ora` file

   ```
   S1 =
     (DESCRIPTION =
       (ADDRESS_LIST =
         (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = <host>)(PORT = 1521))
       )
       (CONNECT_DATA =
         (SERVICE_NAME = s1.orcl.com)
       )
     )

   S2 =
     (DESCRIPTION =
       (ADDRESS_LIST =
         (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = <host>)(PORT = 1522))
       )
       (CONNECT_DATA =
         (SERVICE_NAME = s2.orcl.com)
       )
     )
   ```
6. Create following trigger

   ```
   create or replace TRIGGER SFILTER 
   AFTER LOGON ON DATABASE 
     Declare 

       us VARCHAR2(50);
       serv VARCHAR2(20);
       e_nologon EXCEPTION;

     BEGIN

       -- Get username 

       SELECT SYS_CONTEXT ('USERENV', 'SESSION_USER') into us FROM DUAL;   

       -- Get Service Name

       SELECT SYS_CONTEXT ('USERENV', 'SERVICE_NAME') into serv FROM DUAL;

       -- Condition

       if ((us='U1') and (serv!='S1')) or ((us='U2') and (serv!='S2'))  
       then
         RAISE e_nologon;
       end if;

     EXCEPTION 
          WHEN e_nologon THEN 
             RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001,'This user not allowed to login to this service');

     END;
   ```

References:

http://searchoracle.techtarget.com/answer/Killing-the-session-through-an-AFTER-
LOGON-trigger

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions165.htm

Comment: A solution in search of a problem.  And a maintenance nightmare as users come and go.

Comment: I agree with you @EdStevens , It's not a normal case, even in references they don't recommend it. But it just solve this particular request.

Comment: if someone asks me how to poke themselves in the eye with a sharp stick, I am certainly not going to tell them how to sharpen the stick.  We need to find out the OP's real problem, not how to provide him with an ill-conceived solution.